# Check if script was started in current shell

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

Is there a way to check within a shell script (ksh) whether or not the script was started in the current shell?

**Example**

Start script in current shell with `.` (dot/source) command

```
$ . ./myscript
$ I run in the current environment!
```

Start script in own process

```
$ ./myscript
$ I run in my own process!
```

Comment: @tripleee the post you mention stand for bash **and** ksh, while this post seem specific to ksh.

Comment: The exact version of the korn shell being used is very relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple trick you can use.

```
#!/bin/ksh
if [ ${.sh.file} != ${0} ]; then
    echo I run in the current environment
else
    echo I run in my own process
fi
```

Comment: `${.sh.file}` leads to error message `bad substitution` on my side.

Comment: @TechnoCore - I realized you might not be using GNU `ksh`. You cam simply replace `.sh.file` with `_`. The statement will then be `if [ ${_} != ${0} ]; then`.

Answer (score 0):

Every Shell Has its Own PID ..

so you can use **echo "$$"** in ur script ..it will helps us find from where the Script is RAN .

i.e Difference in pid means they are run from different shells .